# VBA - Date Reference

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and have a pretty simple question. I built a macro that updates a data set  periodically and one of the functions of the macro is that it checks to make sure that if there is data for a previous date that it replaces it.

It uses a cell reference to cross check the data set, however I found that if the date is nor formatted the same then it will not replace it. Ex. if 03/07/18 then it will not replace 03/07/2018.

Any ideas on what I could possibly do to circumvent this issue? Thank you in advance!

Here is the code I have for this part of the macro

```
Dim i As Integer, ValueToFind As Integer, LRow As Integer
    intValueToFind = Sheet8.Range("L6")
    Sheet3.Activate
    LRow = Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To LRow
    If Cells(i, 10).Value = intValueToFind Then
    MsgBox ("Found value on row " & i)
```

Comment: Are the source and target cell values specified as Excel Dates? Specifically short date formatted?

Comment: intValueToFind = cdate(Sheet8.Range("L6"))

Comment: @L0uis yeah both the source and target are short date formatted.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I put that into the code and it did not ever recognize the dates even when the formatting was the same

Comment: Shouldn't intValueToFind be ValueToFind since that's how you initialized that variable? It's not a big deal since you don't seem to have Option Explicit in your code.  My next question then is should [int]ValueToFind be an integer? Date and Time uses double, no? Maybe there lies your problem.

Comment: please provide [mcve] which would include specific example of your input data & desired output.

Comment: @DavidZemens thanks for the help David!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might do something like this:

```
Dim i As Long, dateToFind As Date, LRow As Long, checkValue As Variant

dateToFind = CDate(Sheet8.Range("L6").Value)
Sheet3.Activate
LRow = Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To LRow
    checkValue = Cells(i, 10).Value
    If IsDate(checkValue) Then
        If dateToFind = CDate(checkValue) Then
            MsgBox ("Found value on row " & i)
        End If
    End If
Next
```

It seems like you were declaring everything to be an integer, when it's not really. Also, I use Long data types out of habit, which is why I changed your two Integers (that ARE integers) to Longs.

VBA has a built in "Date" data type, which you can read more about [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/date-data-type). Basically, we're assigning the date to dateToFind (a Date data type), and we're using the function CDate to force the value of cell L6 to be a Date data type.

Then, we're looping through your cells, and assigning the value to a variant. We're then checking that value to see if it's "like" a date, as determined by VBA's [IsDate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/isdate-function) function. If it is, we'll force it into a Date data type with CDate, and check it against dateToFind.

Note, we had to check if the value was a date with IsDate before using CDate because if the cell value is NOT in a date format, forcing it to be a Date type will throw an error. We didn't check the first time because we can be reasonably confident that the specific date cell you're using (L6) is, in fact, a Date.

Hopefully that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to clear and reapply date format ?
Something like this :

```
Dim i As Integer, ValueToFind As Integer, LRow As Integer


    'Clear and apply a date format
    Sheet8.Range("L6").ClearFormats
    Sheet8.Range("L6").NumberFormat = "yyyy/mm/dd"

    Columns(10).Select
    Columns(10).ClearFormats
    Columns(10).NumberFormat = "yyyy/mm/dd"

    intValueToFind = Sheet8.Range("L6")

    Sheet3.Activate

    LRow = Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To LRow

    If Cells(i, 10).Value = intValueToFind Then
    MsgBox ("Found value on row " & i)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that still gives me the same error. Thanks for the help though!